Mongoose Plugin to filter soft deleted in array docs and root docs using find() and perform soft delete on array docs and root docs
Implementing a Mongoose Plugin for Soft Delete Array docs and root docs and Filtering soft deleted Array docs and root docs.
I am developing a Mongoose plugin to handle soft deletion and filtering of soft-deleted items using find() in a MongoDB database. The plugin needs to:

Automatically filter out soft-deleted documents and nested array items in find() queries.
Provide a method to perform soft deletion on both top-level documents and nested array items.
Allow the option to include soft-deleted items in queries when needed.

My main challenges are:

Ensuring the pre-find hook efficiently filters both top-level and nested soft-deleted items.
Implementing a flexible soft delete method that works for various document structures.
Handling the option to show soft-deleted items without complicating the query process.

I am particularly interested in:

Handling of nested documents and arrays.

Any guidance or example patterns would be greatly appreciated!
Data  :
 {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "66c883a5e6ddbf5f720ae1b6"
      },
      "name": "Some Name",
      "email": "email@email.com",
      "age": 48,
      "nestedArr": [
        {
          "id": 7032086,
          "value": "apple0",
          "isDeleted": false
        },
        {
          "id": 4086837,
          "value": "apple0",
          "isDeleted": true
        },
        {
          "id": 6683277,
          "value": "apple0",
          "isDeleted": false
        },
        {
          "id": 2870389,
          "value": "apple0",
          "isDeleted": true
        }
      ],
      "isDeleted": true,
    }


Below are logics made to just understand mechanism of projection & filter in pre-hook mongoose schema in case to create soft-delete plugin:
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

// Define User Schema
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 2,
    maxlength: 50,
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
  nestedArr: [
    {
      id: Number,
      value: String,
      isDeleted: Boolean,
    },
  ],

  isDeleted: Boolean,
});

// User Plugin
function softDeletePlugin(schema, options) {
  schema.add({
    isDeleted: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: true,
      default: false,
    },
  });

  schema.pre("find", function (next) {
    const filter = this.getQuery();
    const options = this.getOptions();

    //In case we need to show soft deleted items  (We can also put in getOptions() but I have put in filter)
    if (filter.showSoftDeleted) {
      delete filter["showSoftDeleted"];
      this.setQuery(filter);
      return next();
    }

    // Filter out root (top-level) documents where isDeleted is true
    if (!filter.hasOwnProperty("isDeleted")) {
      filter.isDeleted = { $ne: true };
    }

    // For Array documents. Using $filter will bring all matching records unlike $elemMatch which returns 1st matching result
    if (!options.projection) {
      options.projection = {};
    }
    options.projection.nestedArr = {
      $filter: {
        input: "$nestedArr",
        as: "item",
        cond: { $ne: ["$$item.isDeleted", true] },
      },
    };

    this.setQuery(filter);
    this.setOptions(options);

    return next();
  });

  // Static soft delete method
  schema.statics.softDelete = function (
    conditionFilter,
    nestedRecord = false,
    nestedRecordKey = "nestedArr"
  ) {
    let softDeleteInstance;
    if (nestedRecord) {
      const updateQuery = {
        $set: {
          [`${nestedRecordKey}.$[elem].isDeleted`]: true,
        },
      };

      softDeleteInstance = this.updateMany(conditionFilter, updateQuery, {
        arrayFilters: [
          { [`elem._id`]: conditionFilter[`${nestedRecordKey}._id`] },
        ],
      }).exec();
    }

    //check if _id is given to soft delete root document
    //update root documents (top-level documents) if required to delete.
    if (conditionFilter._id) {
      const updateQuery = {
        $set: {
          isDeleted: true,
        },
      };
      softDeleteInstance = this.updateMany(conditionFilter, updateQuery).exec();
    }

    return softDeleteInstance;
  };
}

// Apply the plugin to the schema
userSchema.plugin(softDeletePlugin);

// User model
const User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);

// Connect to MongoDB
mongoose
  .connect("mongodb://localhost/userdb")
  .then(() => console.log("Connected to MongoDB"))
  .catch((err) => console.error("Could not connect to MongoDB", err));

// How to use :

//soft deletes only array documents
User.softDelete(
  {
    "nestedArr.id": 4086837,
  },
  true
).then(() => console.log("Soft deleted"));

// to soft delete both root & array documents
User.softDelete(
  {
    _id: "66c883a5e6ddbf5f720ae1b6",
    "nestedArr.id": 4086837,
  },
  true
).then(() => console.log("Soft deleted"));

User.find({})
  .lean()
  .then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
  });

/*
  1st argument : conditionFilter
  2nd argument : projection
  3rd argument : to provide Options -> getOptions() in mongoose schema

  // showSoftDeleted to include soft deleted items
  User.find({showSoftDeleted : true}, null, {});

  */

